# SQL return multiple columns based of there max date and the date is less than certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, where-clause

What I am trying to do is find the 'newest' Ad Rates based on its date. I need to return multiple columns which will be grouped by the store. I am using SSMS. and below is a screen shot of what the table looks like with all the values. Disregard the Id.

[image]

As you will see, there are multiple store numbers out there. There will also be a parameter passed into this select where the AdRateDate can not be larger than.

So if my parameter is Declare @toDate DateTime = '2022-11-30 00:00:00.000'

Then the data return should be

[image]

Here is the script I was trying, and I am lost!

```sql
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = '2022-11-30 00:00:00.000'  
SELECT StoreNumber, AdRate  
FROM StoreAdRate  
WHERE AdRateDate =  
 (Select Max(AdRateDate) From StoreAdRate Where AdRateDate <= @ToDate And StoreNumber = StoreNumber)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your statement is on the right track and just lack alias to differentiate between StoreNumber in sub-query and main query.

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = '2022-11-30 00:00:00.000';

SELECT StoreNumber, AdRate
FROM StoreAdRate sar
WHERE AdRateDate = (Select Max(AdRateDate) From StoreAdRate sub 
                    Where sub.AdRateDate <= @ToDate 
                    And sub.StoreNumber = sar.StoreNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

So for each store you want to get the most recently given `AdRate` (and the date it was given) before some specified date parameter?

```
SELECT StoreNumber AdRate, AdRateDate
FROM (
  SELECT StoreNumber, AdRate, AdRateDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Store Number ORDER BY AdRateDate DESC) AS   RowNumber
  FROM Wherever
  WHERE AdRateData < @ToDate
) T
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```